# Printing characters with ncurses fails

Tags: c, ncurses

I am using XUBUNTU 16.04 and Geany.
I am starting to test the library ncurses. Bu I am not able to show characters. When I run the program a window appears, but the characters "a" and "*" does not appear.

This is my code:

```
#include <ncurses.h>
void line(char ch, int n)
{
 int i;
 for( i = 1; i<=n; i++ )
      addch(ch);
 }

 int main()
 {
  clear();
  line("a", 50);
  line("*", 8);
  return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

`man curs_refresh`:

> The `refresh` and `wrefresh` routines (or `wnoutrefresh` and `doupdate`) must be called to get actual output to the terminal, as other routines merely manipulate data structures.

So your program is missing a `refresh();`.

It also looks like you're missing initialization/cleanup, i.e. calling `initscr()` at the beginning and `endwin()` at the end of your program.

Answer (score 3):

Two things are missing:

- initialization
- something to keep the text on the screen momentarily

Initialization begins with `initscr` (or `newterm`, if you r[ead the manual page](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/ncurses.3x.html#h3-Initialization)).  As written, the program would print something to the screen, and exit without pausing (and if your terminal uses the alternate screen, the text would vanish).  A `getch` ([read a character from the keyboard](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_getch.3x.html#h3-Reading-characters)) does that, as well as doing `refresh`.  By the way, the `clear` is unnecessary, because [`initscr` does that](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_initscr.3x.html#h3-initscr):

> The **`initscr`** code determines the terminal type and initializes all curses data structures.  **initscr also causes the first call to  refresh(3x)
>   to  clear  the  screen**.  If errors occur, **`initscr`** writes an appropriate
>   error message to standard error and exits; otherwise, a pointer is  returned to **`stdscr`**.

Try this:

```
#include <curses.h>
void line(char ch, int n)
{
 int i;
 for( i = 1; i<=n; i++ )
      addch(ch);
 }

 int main()
 {
  initscr();
  cbreak();
  noecho();
  line("a", 50);
  line("*", 8);
  getch();
  endwin();
  return 0;
 }
```